# Need help clarifying Parse.User.setPassword documentation

Tags: javascript, parse-server

I am trying to implement two way to reinitialize a user password in a JS application using Parse.
Since I'll need a way to directly set the password, I searched [Parse.User documentation](https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.User.html#methods_setPassword) for a function to update the password field, hoping to know if I am supposed to hash it myself, and how I should use it.

Unfortunately, [the official documentation](https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.User.html#methods_setPassword) is quite unhelpful:

> `Boolean setPassword( password, options )`
>
> Calls `set("password", password, options)` and returns the result.
>   Parameters:
>
> password `<String>`
>      options `<Object>`
>
> A Backbone-style options object.
>
> Returns: `<Boolean>`

What I was expecting to know was if I was supposed to hash the password before providing it, if there is a difference between `setPassword` and `set("password"...)`, and which options are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying and testing, I can conclude that:

- `setPassword()` is just a shortcur of `set('password')`
- The options available are the common ones: `useMasterKey`, `sessionToken`...
- Setting the password automatically hash it.